# Employee turnover in Japanese

Tags: meaning, english-to-japanese

When looking up the terms "Employee retention" and "Employee turnover" on Google Translate I get the following:

Employee retention: 従業員保持

Employee turnover: 従業員の売上高

I'm fairly certain that the translation for "employee turnover" is not what I'm looking for. So what would be the correct term/phrase to use?

Like how would the following statement be said in Japanese: Company X's high turnover rate could imply they have a problem with employee retention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary translation for *retention* is indeed 保持, but this word is not used with humans. Better words used in the human resource or marketing field would be (人材)確保(のための施策), (顧客)関係の維持, つなぎ止め, etc. A katakana word [リテンション](http://www.elite-network.co.jp/x/dictionary/bizwords/retention.html) is also used in this sense.

Turnover is 転職率/離職率/移動率 when you want a technical term. 入れ替わり is also common although this sounds less formal/technical.

> Company X's high turnover rate could imply they have a problem with employee retention.
>   X社の高い離職率は、この会社が人材の確保や維持に問題を抱えている可能性を示している。

Casually, you can say: X社は人の入れ替わりが激しい。社員をつなぎ止めるのに苦労しているんだろう。

Answer (score 4):

I think the best word for your context would be 離職率{りしょくりつ}.

> 従業員の離職率は高いです。
>   The employee turnover rate is high.

Comment: Ahhh perfect! Thanx!